# How to mention @channel(All the team members) using slack api while post message

Tags: c#, api, slack

I want to post a message in slack using api. How can I mention all the team members of a channel just like @channel in slack?

Answer (score 38):

You can use `<!channel>`.

[Example](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22Hello%20%3C!channel%3E%22%7D)

You can see all the possible @mentions in [Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#special-mentions) under *Special mentions*